# Collect an image from Firebase storage (kotlin)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm developing a simple customer profile page for my app.

**What I need:**

This page has to display the customer's profile image and to allow to change it, uploading the selected one to Firebase storage and the URI referement to the Firebase Realtime Database.

**What I did:**

The CustomerMainActivity has a bottom navigation with four tab. One is for the customer profile, so it hosts the `CustomerProfileFragment` that is shown below. The layout of the fragment has an `ImageView` (`ivCustomerProfile`) for the profile picture, and a FAB (`fabCustomerImageEdit`) to choose a new one.

```kotlin
package com.mrizzo.cutitapp.fragments

import ...

private const val ARG_UID = "uid"

/**
 * Profile [Fragment] for the Customer side.
 * Use the [CustomerProfileFragment.newInstance] factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
class CustomerProfileFragment : Fragment()
{
    private lateinit var db: DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var storage: StorageReference
    private lateinit var getImageActivityLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<String>

    private var uid: String? = null
    private var customer: Customer? = null

    // view binding
    private var _binding: FragmentCustomerProfileBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            uid = it.getString(ARG_UID)  // get the UID from the passed parameter
        }

        storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference
        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View
    { // Here all the binding related action must done
        _binding = FragmentCustomerProfileBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false) // inflate the layout for this fragment

        addUserEventListener(uid!!, db)  // add a listener to get the User from the DB

        // create the Activity Launcher for the image selection and upload
        getImageActivityLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri: Uri? ->

            if (uri != null) // if the user goes back without choosing an image, the URI would be null
            {
                binding.ivCustomerProfile.setImageURI(uri)  // show the selected picture

                val bitmap = (binding.ivCustomerProfile.drawable as BitmapDrawable).bitmap  // treat the image as a bitmap
                val byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream)
                val byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()

                // save the image on firebase storage
                val uploadTask = storage.child(Constants.STORAGE_IMAGES).child(uid!!).putBytes(byteArray)
                uploadTask.addOnFailureListener {
                    Toast.makeText(this.context, Constants.MSG_IMAGE_UPLOAD_FAILED, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                uploadTask.addOnCompleteListener {
                    // add the imageUriString got from the storage also to the realtime DB
                    storage.child(Constants.STORAGE_IMAGES).child(uid!!).downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { imageUri: Uri? ->
                        db.child(Constants.DB_CUSTOMERS).child(uid!!).child(Constants.DB_IMAGE_URI_STRING).setValue(imageUri.toString())
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // add the listeners
        binding.apply {

            fabCustomerImageEdit.setOnClickListener {
                getImageActivityLauncher.launch("image/*") // image upload
            }
            ...
        }
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView()
    {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null  // needed to destroy the binding when the fragment is destroyed
    }

    /**
     * Adds a [ValueEventListener] for a specific user in the DB.
     * Changes the informations shown in the UI when the User in the DB changes.
     *
     * @param uid UID of the user
     * @param db DB reference
     */
    private fun addUserEventListener(uid: String, db: DatabaseReference)
    {
        val customerReference = db.child(Constants.DB_CUSTOMERS).child(uid)
        val customerListener = object : ValueEventListener {

            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot)
            {
                // get User object from the DB
                customer = dataSnapshot.getValue<Customer>()

                // change the UI informations accordingly
                binding.apply {
                    tvCustomerFullname.text = customer?.fullName
                    tvCustomerEmail.text = customer?.email

                    if (customer?.preference == Constants.PREF_FEMALE)
                        chipGroup.check(chipFemale.id)
                    else
                        chipGroup.check(chipMale.id)

                    swNotifications.isChecked = customer?.notifications!!

                    if (customer?.imageUriString!!.isNotEmpty())
                    {
                        storage.child(Constants.STORAGE_IMAGES).child(uid).downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
                            ivCustomerProfile.setImageURI(it)
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError)
            {
                Log.w(getString(R.string.app_name), "CustomerProfileFragment:onCancelled", databaseError.toException())
            }
        }

        customerReference.addValueEventListener(customerListener)
    }

    companion object
    {
        /**
         * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
         * this fragment using the provided parameters.
         *
         * @param uid UID of the logged [Customer]
         * @return A new instance of fragment CustomerProfileFragment
         */
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(uid: String) =
            CustomerProfileFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(ARG_UID, uid)  // pass the parameters to the created Fragment
                }
            }
    }
}
```

When the user clicks on the FAB, an activity for choosing the image is started. That image is shown in the ImageView, uploaded to Firebase storage, then the image's URI is saved also in the Firebase Realtime Database. Please, notice that the property `imageUriString` of the `Customer` class is a simple `String`.

All these stuff seem to work.

The `addUserEventListener()` is responsible for updating the image in the `ImageView` when the `Customer` stored in the Firebase Realtime DB changes. **It doesn't work**:

```
2022-07-22 12:24:45.071 26609-26609/com.mrizzo.cutitapp E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https:/firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/cutitapp-unibs.appspot.com/o/images%2FbyupIDEMZ0Q0eWq2csQJqaS8X882?alt=media&token=f88e5405-55de-4f76-8cba-8be77a921088 (No such file or directory)
2022-07-22 12:24:45.071 26609-26609/com.mrizzo.cutitapp W/ImageView: resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/cutitapp-unibs.appspot.com/o/images%2FbyupIDEMZ0Q0eWq2csQJqaS8X882?alt=media&token=f88e5405-55de-4f76-8cba-8be77a921088
```

Sorry, I'm a totally beginner in Android and Kotlin.
What should I do? Thank You all.

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot see what's wrong at a first glance. Perhaps someone else does, but since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46) will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the **problem**, after a lot of coffee.

The method `setImageURI()` of `ImageView` does not accept an URL, but just a local URI. I suspected that since the provided URI was parsed with a single `/` after `https:`, as you can see from the stack trace:

```
E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https:/firebasestorage.googleapis.com/... (No such file or directory)
```

The **solution** is to download the image from the Firebase storage as a Bitmap, then display it in the `ImageView`.

```kotlin
if (customer?.imageUriString!!.isNotEmpty())
{
    val imageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(customer?.imageUriString!!)
    imageRef.getBytes(10 * 1024 * 1024).addOnSuccessListener {
        val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(it, 0, it.size)
        ivCustomerProfileImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
    }.addOnFailureListener {
        // Handle any errors
    }
}
```

The code is rough, but it works.
I hope it will be helpful.